# Sum of bases for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two lists of $n$ distinct vectors $L_1$ and $L_2$. Both lists are bases for a vector space $\mathbf{V}$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$.
Let $L_1=(a_1;…a_n)$ and $L_2=(b_1;…b_n)$, where $\{a_i;b_i\}\in \mathbf{V}$ are basis vectors.
Let
$$L_1+L_2=(a_1+b_{1};…;a_n+b_{n})$$I want to prove or disprove wether if $L_1+L_2$ is also a basis for $\mathbf{V}$, but i just managed to tackle the problem for linearly dependent lists. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\{a_1,a_2\}$ is a basis for a two dimensional space then  so is $\{-a_1,a_2\}$. Adding these we get {0,2a_2}$ which is not a basis.