# Sum of bases of a vector space for an arbitrary permutation.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, permutations

I have two lists of $n$ distinct vectors $L_1$ and $L_2$. Both lists are bases for a vector space $\mathbf{V}$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with dimension $d>1$.
Let $L_1=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and $L_2=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$, where $\{a_i;b_j\}\in \mathbf{V}$ are basis vectors. Let
$$L_1+\sigma(L_2)=(a_1+b_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,a_n+b_{\sigma(n)})$$I need to prove or disprove wether if every $L_1+\sigma(L_2)$ is also a basis for $\mathbf{V}$ for some $\sigma\in\mathbf{S}_n$. I made a similar question for the case in wich $\sigma$ is the identity, so i’ll post the link here. This one would be a sort of generalization of the previous question, wich showed that, at least for the identity in $\mathbf{S}_n$, the sum of bases might not be a base.

**link to original question**: [Sum of bases for a vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4594926/sum-of-bases-for-a-vector-space)

Comment: By that i mean that any sum of $a_i$ and $b_j$ (I have to edit the subscript in b) are vectors in the space, and since every sum of vectors in the space is also in the space, the sum of the lists of vectors is also a list of vectors for any permutation. Remains to show linear independence and span of the list to show its a base.

Comment: Here's a counterexample that you may wish to dismiss as trivial: if $V = \Bbb{R}$, so $n = 1$, and we take $a_1 = 1$ and $b_1 = -1$, then there is only one permutation $\sigma$, and the sum comes to $0$, which is not a basis.

Comment: Or, a trickier to dismiss counterexample: take $((1, 0), (0, 1))$ and $((-1, 0), (0, -1))$. The possible permutations produce a sum of $((0, 0), (0, 0))$ and $((1, -1), (-1, 1))$, neither of which are bases.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks, indeed, i wish to avoid the case in wich $Dim(\mathbf{V})=1$. I’ll edit rigth away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, from my comments, I think I've talked myself into thinking this is not true, and cannot be obviously salvaged.

Take $L_1 = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ to be any basis, and form $L_2$ by $b_i = -a_i$. then, for any $\sigma \in S_n$. Then $L_1 + \sigma(L_2)$ is not a basis.

Why? If $\sigma$ is not a derangement, then $L_1 + \sigma(L_2)$ contains a $0$ vector, which precludes it from being a basis. Otherwise, map this basis under the coordinate vector map with respect to $L_1$. Then, every coordinate vector contains exactly one $1$, exactly one $-1$, and $0$s elsewhere. If $L_1 + \sigma(L_2)$ were a basis, we would expect these coordinate vectors to span $\Bbb{F}^n$. But, this is not the case, as all these coordinate vectors have their entries sum to $0$. Either way, $L_2 + \sigma(L_1)$ is not a basis.

EDIT: Or, slightly more generally, one could also just take any bases $L_1$ and $L_2$ such that the sum of all vectors from both bases is $0$. Then, the sum of $L_1 + \sigma(L_2)$ will be $0$, which would contradict linear independence.

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Thanks. I’ll continue to investigate more special cases.